# Analyzing Windows crash dumps generated on XP/32 machines with Win7/64?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windbg, crash-dumps

We have a problem with analyzing our Windows crash-dumps that were created on customer Windows XP/32 boxes on our development machines.

Many of our development machines are now Win7/64 boxes, but it appears that the crash-dumps generated under Windows XP cannot full resolve their binary dependency, thereby leading to warnings when displaying the call stacks in Visual Studio (2005).

For example, the msvcr80.dll cannot be resolved when loaded from a Win7 machine when the dump was generated on Windows XP:

On XP, the WinSxS path appears to be `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_e6967989\msvcr80.dll` -- on Win7, the WinSxS path to the **same** DLL version seems to be: `x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d08d7da0442a985d`

(I got this info from [a forum thread on codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1805840&postcount=7) that link to [an msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235342%28VS.80%29.aspx).)

Visual Studio (2005) can now no longer correctly resolve the binaries for the crash-dump.

How can I get Visual Studio to resolve *all* the correct binaries for my dump file?

**Note**: I have already correctly set up the symbol server. The public symbols for most system DLLs (kernel32.dll, etc) and our symbols of our own DLLs are correctly loaded. It is just that the symbols of DLLs that reside in the WinSxS folder are *not* loaded, because it appears that Vista/7 uses a different path scheme for these DLLs than XP does and therefore Visual Studio cannot find the *dll* (*not* the pdb) on the local dev machine and so cannot load the corresponding symbols for the dump file.

Comment: You have tried `.effmach x86` command?

Comment: @Asha : effmach is a WinDbg command (right?) and anyway, this has less to do with x86 vs. x64 mode, than (I think) with Windows XP vs. Windows Vista/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think WinDbg should be used in this case to analyze the dumps. Then you can get rid of such roadblockers. But just remember to use x86 build of WinDbg (part of Debugging Tools for Windows).

Comment: +1 for the tip about **x86** WinDbg. Unfortunately, I would like to keep WinDbg as a last resort app, as just quickly looking into a dmp file with Visual Studio is lots more convenient and will work pretty well for most standard scenarios.

Comment: I am not sure why you treat WinDbg as a last resort. For crash dumps, it (or DebugDiag) should be the first tool to use, as it is the fastest.

Comment: If a developer already has VS installed, all he's got to do is unzip/checkout our files and double-click the dump file and he's inside a debugging environment he's comfortable with. With WinDbg he's first got to put WinDbg on his machine (trivial) and then get all settings running in WinDbg (rather easy) and then start to learn how to use WinDbg's horrible UI :-)

Comment: That's why Microsoft tries so hard to improve VS debugging experience and also make it as capable as WinDbg. We see some progress in VS2010, but currently WinDbg is still unique in dump analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Use microsoft symbol server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503

To do it, open the options dialog, goto ebugging\Symbols and add http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols as a new location; then select a local path for caching and you are ready to go

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, it's the binaries you are having difficulty resolving not the symbols correct?

Apart from copying over the respective binaries one option is to setup an x86 machine, share out it's C and just point your debugger to that machine.

You could have this in a VM for all your developers to access. When resolving the binaries just load them from the VM.

Comment: Yes, it's the binaries and not the symbols. I'm not sure if the VM is a convenient solution. Manually copying something into the WinSxS folder doesn't seem to be a good idea either though ...

Answer (score 1):

try to use symchk.exe, it help you to pull symbols and binaries from a dump file. (or from a directory)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558845%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

symchk could be found in the windbg package